# What is the best way to move half a million files to another folder based on a list?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

How do I move a large number of files to another folder quickest?

I have a repository of 800,000+ xml files from the IRS, and I'm trying to move a subset (approx 500,000) to a new folder. So far I've created a batch file that uses a list of filenames to move them. It's working, but it's too slow. The batch file has been executing for about an hour now, but only one file has been moved into the new folder.

Is there anyway I could improve the efficiency of my batch file? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
@echo off
set Source=C:\Users\tenis\OneDrive\Desktop\Data_Projects\Impact_Capital\data\IRS990_2017_2016
set Target=C:\Users\tenis\OneDrive\Desktop\Data_Projects\Impact_Capital\data\IRS990_2017
set FileList=C:\Users\tenis\OneDrive\Desktop\Data_Projects\Impact_Capital\data\filenames_990_2017.txt
echo.

if not exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%Target%" md "%Target%"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%FileList%"') do copy "%Source%\%%a" "%Target%"

:Exit
echo.
echo press the Space Bar to close this window.
pause > nul
```

Comment: You should consider using Robocopy.

Comment: You say you want to move the files, but your code copies them. Do you want to copy or to move them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batch file actually worked! When I hit cntrl c in the command line, files appeared. After rerunning it, I got what I needed.

So I guess the take away from all this is hit cntrl c if you don't know what the script is doing, and have patience. =)

Comment: What most likely happened was that because you were processing the output of `type "%filelist%"` instead of processing `%filelist%` directly, all that waiting was for `type` to finish. When you hit Ctrl+C, you interrupted the command and the `for` loop handled the files that it had gotten through. I'd double-check that all the files are present.

Comment: What logic did you use to build your filelist?  Robocopy has many options to select the specific files you want to copy and do not want to copy.  Plus it is multi-threaded so it will copy faster.  Regardless this is not an answer to your question and should be deleted.